# SQL String contains ONLY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a field that denotes whether the data in that row is valid or not. This field contains a string of undetermined length. I need a query that will only pull out rows where all the characters in this field are N. Some possible examples of this field.

```
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNEEEENNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNOOOOOEEEENNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Any suggestions on a postcard please.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT Field
FROM YourTable
WHERE Field NOT LIKE '%[^N]%' AND Field <> ''
```

What it's doing is a wildcard search, broken down:

The LIKE will find records where the field contains characters other than N in the field. So, we apply a NOT to that as we're only interested in records that do not contain characters other than N. Plus a condition to filter out blank values.

Comment: Thats the ticket... I think I'm just having a bad day as I know all this :S

Comment: @Quassnoi yeah, its like a blind panic when it comes to questions like this to get them answered first ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   field NOT LIKE '%[^N]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which SQL dialect you are using. For example Oracle has several functions you may use. With oracle you could use condition like :

WHERE LTRIM(field, 'N') = ''

The idea is to trim out all N's and see if the result is empty string. If you don't have LTRIM, check if you have some kind of TRANSLATE or REPLACE function to do the same thing.

Another way to do it could be to pick length of your field and then construct comparator value by padding empty string with N. Perhaps something like:

WHERE field = RPAD('', field, 'N)

Oracle pads that empty string with N's and picks number of pad characters from length of the second argument. Perhaps this works too:

WHERE field = RPAD('', LENGTH(field), 'N)

I haven't tested those, but hopefully that give you some ideas how to solve your problem. I guess that many of these solutions have bad performance if you have lot of rows and you don't have other WHERE conditions to select proper index.

Comment: Hey, thats a clever solution. You could do the same in MSQL with the replace function.